# react-navigation wrap root AppContainer with react Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm looking for the way to manage global state across my react-native app using react-navigation. I tried to implement basic React Context, which I wanted to wrap around the react-navigation's `createAppContainer()` method but it didn't work.

I ended up wrapping an app container from `index.js` file using Context's HOC, but it seems like react-navigation has a problem with re-rendering of nested components, when Context's state is changed. I can access my Context from nested Components but they just aren't re-rendered when context state is changed.

My `index.js` file looks like:

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./src/App";
import { withAppContextProvider } from "./src/AppContext";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => withAppContextProvider(App));
```

My context class looks like:

```
// for new react static context API
export const AppContext = createContext({});

// create the consumer as higher order component
export const withAppContext = ChildComponent => props => (
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    {context => <ChildComponent {...props} global={context} />}
  </AppContext.Consumer>
);

// create the Provider as higher order component (only for root Component of the application)
export const withAppContextProvider = ChildComponent => props => (
  <AppContextProvider>
    <ChildComponent {...props} />
  </AppContextProvider>
);

export class AppContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isOnline: true
  };

  handleConnectivityChange = isOnline => {
    this.setState({ isOnline });
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      "connectionChange",
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      "connectionChange",
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

my `App.js` file looks like:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Cities: CitiesScreen
  },
  getStackConfig({ initialRouteName: "Home" })
);

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Settings: SettingsScreen
  },
  getStackConfig({ initialRouteName: "Settings" })
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeStack,
      Settings: SettingsStack
    }
  )
);
```

`CitiesScreen` component example:

```
import { AppContext } from "../AppContext";

class CitiesScreen extends Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This value should change on isOnline update: {this.context.isOnline}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I'm accessing Context, from for example `CitiesScreen` component, I'm currently able to get the value of `isOnline` state of context but whenever I switch my internet connection (on android emulator) on/off, the context state is changed but the component isn't re-rendered and my `shouldComponentUpdate()` method isn't triggered. Any help to make this work?

Comment: Nobody to help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I downgraded React from 16.8 to 16.5.0, react navigation version is 3.
I'm still investigating but that's a temporary solution for now.